# Annotated bibliography with math in annotations

Tags: bibliographies

I have a bibtex file like

```
@article{Ancey2014a,
author = {Ancey, C. and Heyman, J.},
journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
number = {2014},
pages = {129--168},
title = {{A microstructural approach to bed load transport: mean behaviour and fluctuations of particle transport rates}},
volume = {744},
year = {2014},
}
```

I would like to produce a command \annote{} which acts like the following.

```
\annote{Ancey2014a}

Here is a description of the \cite{Ancey2014a} paper. 
I can use math. $2+2=4$.
```

This should return in the compiled document

```
[1] C. Ancey and J. Heyman, “A microstructural approach to bed load transport: mean behaviour
and fluctuations of particle transport rates,” Journal of Fluid Mechanics, vol. 744, no. 2014,
pp. 129–168, 2014.

Here is a description of the Ancey and Heyman [2014] paper. I can use math. 2+2 = 4.
```

The idea is that annote would be an in place reference. I have been using the IEEEannote style file to include annotations but this is proving not flexible enough because I cannot use math or special symbols in my annotations. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Mhhh, I would have expected that maths like `$2+2=4$` would work in the annotation. Can you give an example of how exactly it fails for you?